# How to efficiently flatten a list of Either in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I have a list something like this `List<Either<Failure, List<MyResult>>>` and would like to flatten it to `Either<Failure, List<MyResult>>` using Arrow-kt but everything I've tried seems pretty clunky and ends up traversing the list twice.
It feels like there should be a better way but I can't figure it out.
Here's a contrived example of what I have now:

```
val things : List<MyThing> = /* some stuff */
val results : List<Either<Failure, List<MyResult>>> = things.map { doThingThatReturnsEither(it) }
val successes : List<MyResult> = results.mapNotNull { it.orNull() }.flatten()
val firstFailure : Failure? = results.mapNotNull { it.swap().orNull() }.firstOrNull()
return firstFailure?.let {it.left()} ?: success.right()
```

Any suggestions welcome!

Bonus question: is there a way to shortcut `things.map { }` if one of them comes back with a `Left`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `sequence`

```
val res:Either<Failure, List<MyResult>> = results.sequence(Either.applicative())
    .fix()
    .map { it.fix() }
```

this will short circuit on the first `Failure` (if any) and return it as left, or give you all of `MyResult` as list.

the `fix()` and `map { it.fix() }` is needed because of Arrow's emulation of higher kinded types.

Comment: I had to `flatten()` in the extra `map` to get my desired results but this is way better than what I had before thanks.

Comment: Hi 
Arrow 1.1.5 removed all extenstion functions.
can you please suggest a solutionm with latest library ?
https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-core/tree/40619f87b7fc1c790c3ab7b7341005a960630a27/arrow-core/src/main/kotlin/arrow/core/extensions

Comment: @ArjunNagathankandy `sequence` is still there: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/sequence.html